# Page numbering in lower right corner (classicthesis)

Tags: lyx, page-numbering, classicthesis

I'm using classicthesis 4.1 in LyX to write my thesis and I need help with the page numbering.

How do I force the all page numbers to stay at the lower right corner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`classicthesis` uses the `scrpage2` package to customize the headers and footers; you can add the page to the footer alway to the right with a redefinition of the `scrheadings` page style:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
    \clearscrheadings
    \setheadsepline{0pt}
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{@nochapters}}%
        {\relax}%
        {\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\enspace\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}} 
    \lehead{\headmark}
    \rohead{\headmark}
    \refoot{\thepage}
    \rofoot{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headfont}{\small}  
%    \DeclareRobustCommand{\fixBothHeadlines}[2]{} % <--- ToDo
    % hack to get the content headlines right (thanks, Lorenzo!)
        \def\toc@heading{%
            \ifthenelse{\boolean{@nochapters}}%
            {\section*{\contentsname}}%nochapters
            {\chapter*{\contentsname}}%chapters
            \@mkboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\section{Test section}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

A detail of the bottom of two consecutive pages:

[image]

Comment: You mean package `scrpage2`?

Comment: @karlkoeller hahaha! Of course! I've fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thank you, it did the job for the arabic page numbering, but unfortunately not the roman page numbering on the Frontmatter. It runs with `\frenchspacing \raggedbottom \pagenumbering{roman} \pagestyle{plain}`.

Comment: @user212704 seems like you need to redefine the `plain` style.